# Sequence to Sequence transformer model for harmonizing a melody: data representation, embedding, and interpretation

Tags: pytorch, midi, word-embedding, transformer-model

I am developing a seq2seq model using a transformer model and PyTorch. The network should take in a sequence representing a melody and output a sequence of the same length indicating an appropriate harmony at the corresponding time-step. The model is going to be trained on a data set of J.S. Bach chorales, where each time-step has a melody (soprano) and three harmony (alto, tenor, bass) notes. I have been toying with a couple of ways to represent the data:

1. MIDI integer encoding - if the length of a chorale is 640 time-steps, then the entire chorale would be a (640, 4) tensor, and each of the four elements in a row contains the MIDI integer of the note (e.g. middle C = 60).
2. Many-hot MIDI encoding - the chorale would be a tensor of size (640, R), where R is the range of notes under consideration for input and generation. Each row in the tensor would be a many hot vector where the index corresponding to the MIDI integer of the active notes of each voice would be 1 and the rest 0.

I have been able to scan through the dataset and see how many unique melody notes and how many unique harmony combinations there are. I have been assuming that that is the size of my respective vocabularies. I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how PyTorch's `nn.Embedding` works. So here are my questions:

1. Inside the model definition, my `Embedding` layers for the encoder and decoder are set with vocabulary lengths of `len(unique_melody_notes) + 3` and `len(unique_chords) + 3` respectively. I add 3 to these in order to include a start-of-sequence, end-of-sequence, and padding token in each vocab. But when training begins when using the many-hot data representation, I get `IndexError: index out of range in self` exception in the embedding layer. I was under the impression that the `nn.Embedding` layer is simply a mapping between sparse vectors and dense embeddings determined by the layer. How am I misunderstanding the `nn.Embedding` layer that these many-hot vectors are not able to be fed to them.
2. Since the MIDI integer encoding is already a dense representation, do I even need embedding?

I can provide code or data examples if need be. Please help me to understand, and please correct me if I am misunderstanding something.

EDIT: I figured out what my problem was; since the range of the MIDI integers for the melody was {58, 61, ..., 83}, I set the embedding vocab size based on the length of that sequence directly but did not account for shifting the vocab down, so `num_embeddings` was 27 (length of vocab + padding token) but I was directly passing indices in the range [58-83].

However, now I might be facing a different issue, and this stems from my lack of understanding about what the transformer model is supposed to be doing. I will try to include only necessary code here. I have constructed vocab dictionaries for both the input and target sequences, which have different sizes as there are more unique harmonic combinations than unique melody notes. Here is my data loader:

```
#functions to retrieve pytorch tensor of vocab indices
def get_harm_index_from_vocab(data):
    t = torch.tensor([harm_dict_seq_2_idx[tuple(seq)] for seq in data])
    return t

def get_mel_index_from_vocab(data):
    t = torch.tensor([mel_dict_note_2_idx[n] for n in data])
    return t

class MusicDataSetMidi(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_array_file, sos, eos, transform=None):
        self.data_arr = np.load(data_array_file) #read data into array from file
        self.sos = sos #Not used currently
        self.eos = eos #not used currently
        self.transform = transform
    
    def __len__(self):
        return np.shape(self.data_arr)[0] #first dimension of data tensor represents number of data    
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        chorale = self.data_arr[idx,:,:] #select chorale 'idx' with shape (640, 4)    
        if self.transform:
            chorale = self.transform(chorale)
            
        #Extract first column representing time series of melody in MIDI integer format
        mel = get_mel_index_from_vocab(chorale[:, 0])
        #Extract 2nd through 4th columns representing time series of harmony in MIDI integer format 
        harm = get_harm_index_from_vocab(chorale[:, 1:])
        
        return mel, harm
```

Now the input sequence and target sequence look like
[17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, ..., 13, 13, 0, 0, ..., 0] and
[3345, 3345, 3345, 3345, 3359, 3359, ..., 1763, 1763, 4960, 4960, ..., 4960] respectively. 0 is a token representing silence (padding) in the input sequence, and 4960 is the token representing the same in the harmony sequence. These are just the keys used when I constructed the vocab dicts since they are of different sizes.

The following two blocks instantiate the positional encoding module and the entire seq2seq transformer model:

```
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_model, dropout_p, max_length):
        super().__init__()
        """
        dim_model : dimension of the embedded representations used as inputs to the multi-head attention blocks
        dropout_p : probability of dropout in all dropout layers
        max_len   : how far the position can have an effect on a token (like a window of influence)
        """
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_p)
        #Encoding from formula
        pos_encoding = torch.zeros(max_length, 1, dim_model)
        positions_list = torch.arange(max_length).unsqueeze(1)
        division_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, dim_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0)) / dim_model)

        #pos_encoding(pos, 2i) = sin(pos/1000^(2i/dim_model))
        pos_encoding[:, 0, 0::2] = torch.sin(positions_list * division_term)
        #pos_encoding(pos, 2i+1) = cos(pos/1000^(2i/dim_model))
        pos_encoding[:, 0, 1::2] = torch.cos(positions_list * division_term)

        #save as buffer (the same as a parameter but without gradients)
        self.register_buffer('pos_encoding', pos_encoding)
            
    def forward(self, token_embedding: torch.tensor) -> torch.tensor:
        #residual connection + positional encoding
        token_plus_pos_embedding = token_embedding + self.pos_encoding[:token_embedding.size(0), :]
        #send through dropout layer and return
        return self.dropout(token_plus_pos_embedding)
```

and

```
class Transformer(nn.Module):
    #Constructor
    def __init__(
        self,
        dim_model,
        num_heads,
        num_encoder_layers,
        num_decoder_layers,
        melody_vocab_size,
        harmony_vocab_size,
        dropout_p,
        pos_enc_max_len
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.dim_model = dim_model
        # LAYERS
        #Give transformer model an object of our positional encoding class
        self.positional_encoder = PositionalEncoding(
            dim_model=dim_model, dropout_p=dropout_p, max_length=pos_enc_max_len
        )

        #Create embedding layer to turn sequence vectors into dense, continuous vector space
        self.source_embedding = nn.Embedding(melody_vocab_size, dim_model)
        self.target_embedding = nn.Embedding(harmony_vocab_size, dim_model)
        
        #Create transformer layer
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=dim_model, 
            nhead=num_heads, 
            num_encoder_layers=num_encoder_layers,
            num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers,
            dropout=dropout_p
        )
        self.out = nn.Linear(dim_model, harmony_vocab_size)
        
    def forward(self, src, tgt, tgt_mask=None, src_pad_mask=None, tgt_pad_mask=None):
        #src size must be (batch_size, src sequence length)
        #tgt size must be (batch_size, tgt sequence length)
        
        #Embedding + positional encoding: output size = (batch size, sequence length, dim_model)
        src = self.source_embedding(src) * math.sqrt(self.dim_model)
        tgt = self.target_embedding(tgt) * math.sqrt(self.dim_model)
        src = self.positional_encoder(src)
        tgt = self.positional_encoder(tgt)
        
        #Permute embedded/encoded sequences to obtain shape (seqence length, batch size, dim_model)
        src = src.permute(1, 0, 2)
        tgt = tgt.permute(1, 0, 2)
        
        #Pass embedded/encoded sequences to transformer
        transformer_out = self.transformer(
            src, tgt, tgt_mask=tgt_mask, src_key_padding_mask=src_pad_mask, tgt_key_padding_mask=tgt_pad_mask
        )
        out = self.out(transformer_out)
        
        return out
    
    def get_tgt_mask(self, size) -> torch.tensor:
        #Generates a square matrix where each row allows one more 'word' of sequence to be seen
        mask = torch.tril(torch.ones(size, size) == 1)
        mask = mask.float()
        mask = mask.masked_fill(mask==0, float('-inf'))
        mask = mask.masked_fill(mask==1, float(0.0))
        
        # EX for size=5:
        # [[0., -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf],
        #  [0.,   0., -inf, -inf, -inf],
        #  [0.,   0.,   0., -inf, -inf],
        #  [0.,   0.,   0.,   0., -inf],
        #  [0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]
        
        return mask
    
    def create_pad_mask(self, matrix: torch.tensor, pad_token: int) -> torch.tensor:
        # If matrix = [1,2,3,0,0,0] where pad_token=0, the result mask is
        # [False, False, False, True, True, True]
        return (matrix == pad_token)
```

The following two blocks instantiate the model and runs a sample training loop with a batch size of 1:

```
#Set compute device dependent on whether GPU is available
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print(device)

#--------Arguments for transformer model-----------
 
NUM_MELODY_TOK = len(mel_dict_note_2_idx)
NUM_HARMONY_TOK = len(harm_dict_seq_2_idx)
MODEL_DIM = 512  #size of latent embedded vectors passed to the model. Hyperparameter open to tuning
NUM_HEADS = 8 #number of attention heads in multi headed attention modules
NUM_ENC_LAYERS = 4
NUM_DEC_LAYERS = 4
DROPOUT_PROB = 0.1
MAX_POS_ENC_LENGTH = 640
model = Transformer(dim_model=MODEL_DIM,
                   num_heads=NUM_HEADS,
                   num_encoder_layers=NUM_ENC_LAYERS,
                   num_decoder_layers=NUM_DEC_LAYERS,
                   melody_vocab_size=NUM_MELODY_TOK,
                   harmony_vocab_size=NUM_HARMONY_TOK,
                   dropout_p=DROPOUT_PROB,
                   pos_enc_max_len=MAX_POS_ENC_LENGTH).to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, betas=(0.9, 0.98))
loss_fcn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

and

```
def training_loop(model, opt, loss_fn, dataloader):
    
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    pred_max_value = []
    pred_argmax_value = []
    
    for input_melody, target_harmony in dataloader:

        input_melody = torch.tensor(input_melody).to(device)
        target_harmony = torch.tensor(target_harmony).to(device)

        #Shift target sequence so model is lined up correctly to predict next target index in sequence?
        target_input = target_harmony[:, :-1]
        target_expected = target_harmony[:, 1:]

        sequence_length = target_input.size(1)
        tgt_mask = model.get_tgt_mask(sequence_length).to(device)
        
        pred = model(input_melody, target_input, tgt_mask)
        #Put back to batch first order for loss function
        pred = pred.permute(1, 2, 0)
        
        #Keep track of which harmony vocab index the model predicts with highest likelihood
        pred_argmax_value.append(torch.argmax(pred[0,:,0]).item())
        #Keep track of value of highest prob. harmony index to see whether model is uncertain about outputs
        pred_max_value.append(torch.max(pred[0,:,0]).item())
        
        loss = loss_fn(pred, target_expected)
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        total_loss += loss.detach().item()
    return pred, pred_max_value, pred_argmax_value
        
num_epochs = 40
for n in range(num_epochs):   
    pred, mv, amv = training_loop(model, optimizer, loss_fcn, train_dataloader)
```

The following plot shows the model the index of the predicted harmonic sequence for the final epoch.
[image]

Notice how it keeps predicting the silence/padding token of 4690. Also, I have only one prediction per entire sequence presented to the network (the x-axis of the plot ends at 217 which is the number of pieces in the training data set). Here are my new questions:

1. Is the seq2seq model only predicting the harmonic output for the first time step of each data item? If this is the case, do I need to adjust my training loop to predict the entire accompaniment sequence? I am unsure what the model is predicting exactly.
2. Come time for inference on yet unseen sequences, do I need to feed the same melody in a loop to generate the entire accompaniment sequence?
3. The model keeps predicting the silence/padding token. Do I need to use a separate token indicating the end-of-sequence?
4. Do I need a start of sequence token for the input and/or target sequence? In the training loop I offset the targets, but I'm not really sure what's going on there, I copied it from a tutorial.

I would appreciate any help or insight into this problem.

Comment: Some code would be excellent, would be much easier to see where the error is coming from. Neat project btw.

Comment: @BrockBrown I have edited my post and added what I hope is enough code to see what's going on. Please let me know if there is any more information that would be helpful!